# Can MPI scatter dealing with many data txt files

Tags: mapreduce, mpi

Suppose I have many txt files: data1.txt, data2.txt, ..., each contains lines of numbers

And I need to use map reduce to count occurrence of each number.

Can I use scatter to divide those files into parts so that they can be processed at the same time and how?

I know that scatter sends chunks of an array to different processes, but can it also be used to deal with files of data?

if not, how can i do this in MPI?

Comment: `MPI_Scatter()` assumes one process would read **all** the files into memory. That would be very inefficient and memory consuming. If you have many files (e.g. much more than available processes) and they all have similar sizes, then you do not have to worry about load imbalance, and you can simply have each rank opens its files: for example rank `n/p` would open open and process files `data<N>.txt` where `N%p == n`